# Call methods for Hangman

Tags: java

I have all the methods working correctly, but I am confused about how I print the number of guesses remaining and print Hangman in my main method. I need to print the current hangMan by calling `printHangman` but not sure how to call it with no guess counter

```
public class Hangman2
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Welcome to HangMan Player 1, Please enter a word. Player 2, Please close your eyes: ");
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

    String secretWord = stdin.next();

    for (int x = 1; x <= 100; x++)
    {
        System.out.println(" ");
    }

    System.out.println("Clearing Screen");

    System.out.println("The current partial word is: ");
    String initialWord = createPartialWord(secretWord);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("The current hangman picture is: ");




}


    public static String createPartialWord(String secretWord)
    {
        String newsecretWord = "";
        int wordLength = secretWord.length();

         while (wordLength > 0)
            {
                newsecretWord = newsecretWord + "-";
                System.out.print("-");
                wordLength--;
            }
         return newsecretWord;
    }

    public static String replaceChar(String word, char c, int i)
    {

        if(0 < i && i < word.length())
        {
            return word.substring(0, i) + c + word.substring(i + 1);
        }

        return word;
    }

    public static String updatePartialWord(String partial, String secret, char c)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= secret.length(); i++)
        {
            if (secret.charAt(i) == c)
            {

                return replaceChar(partial, c , i);
            }

        }
        return partial;


    }

    public static void printHangman(int guessLeft) 
    {
        String HEAD = " ";
        String BODY = " ";
        String LEGS = " ";
        String LEFTARM = " ";
        String RIGHTARM = " ";

        System.out.println("_____");
        System.out.println("|   |");

        if (guessLeft < 6) 
        {
            HEAD = "()"; 
        }

        System.out.println("| " + HEAD);
        if (guessLeft < 5) 
        {
            BODY = "||";
        }
        if (guessLeft < 4) 
        {
            LEFTARM = "\\";
        }
        if (guessLeft < 3) 
        {
            RIGHTARM = "/";
        }

        System.out.println("| " + LEFTARM + BODY + RIGHTARM);
        if (guessLeft < 2) 
        {
            LEGS = "/";
        }
        if (guessLeft < 1) 
        {
            LEGS += "\\";
        }
        System.out.println("| " + LEGS);
        System.out.println("|_____\n\n\n\n");
    }


}
```

Comment: `"I have all the methods working correctly"` - How can you know that if you haven't been able to actually *call* the methods?  `"not sure how to call it with no guess counter"` - Same way you call any method in Java.  If the method needs an `int` then you have to give it an `int`.  It sounds like your game needs to track how many guesses the user has tried (and potentially any other information about the game being played).

Comment: The other methods work because I called them, I haven't been able to call `printHangman` but know it works because the code was provided from the professor. And yes how do I track guesses tried in `main()`?

Comment: I actually figured out how to call it... just need a guess tracker

Comment: `"know it works because the code was provided from the professor"` - You have *far* too much faith in the average professor's ability to write usable code ;-)  As for how to track guesses, at the very least you'd need an `int` variable which is updated any time the user provides a guess.  For example if you're trying to track how many guesses a user has provided then it would start at zero and increment with each guess.  Or if you want to track how many guesses are remaining then it would start at a pre-set maximum and decrement with each guess.

Answer (score 0):

People are not going to write your assignment for you on this forum and you typically need to try a bit more that just say "I'm stuck." That being said, here's a rough outline to get you past this point:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to HangMan Player 1, Please enter a word. Player 2, Please close your eyes: ");
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

        String secretWord = stdin.next();

        int guessesLeft = /* Number of guesses at the start */;
        String partialWord = createPartialWord(secretWord);

        while (/* You have guesses remaining */)
        {
            for (int x = 1; x <= 100; x++)
            {
                System.out.println(" ");
            }

            System.out.println("Clearing Screen");

            System.out.println("The current partial word is: ");
            System.out.println(partialWord);
            System.out.println("The current hangman picture is: ");

            printHangman(guessesLeft);

            // TODO: Obtain the next letter from the user
            // TODO: Update the partial word with the letter
            // TODO: Make it such that you have one less guess remaining
        }
    }
```

Also, I'm pretty sure `createPartialWord` isn't supposed to have a print statement inside it.